# Notification using kinvey

Tags: android, notifications, kinvey

I am a beginner so I am really sorry if it is a simple question.
I want to have notification in my Android application using Kinvey and GCM that works as follows when user A changes some thing in my database a group of users should be notified i have followed this link http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/push but it handles only receive notification .how can i make my data base feel that something has changed and now it should send a notification?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set over DATABASE but in the **web-service** you have to define that if data is inserted or deleted or whatever happens successfully then Call to GCM server.

Comment: how can i do that using kinvey? is there any tutorial?

Comment: @SohaAbuhamam I know the fundamental concept that i told you in your kinvey :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this using Kinvey Business Logic (BL).

You can set up different types of Kinvey BL scripts depending on each use case (http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/business-logic#types) and execute it to send out push or other notifications accordingly.

Documentation:

1. Kinvey Business Logic: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/business-logic
2. Kinvey BL reference for sending push notifications: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/reference/business-logic/reference.html#push-module

E.g. for a specific collection in data store (database), you can create BL collection hook called onPostSave which will be triggered when an entity in that collection is created/updated.

Comment: Sample: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/nodejs/guides/business-logic#Triggeringpushnotifications